# data transfer through Serial Communication

Tags: c#

In C# i am sending the status byte array and status byte is `0x00` and then i will attach its checksum.

**This is sending button code at C#**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //send status request
            byte[] statusdata = new byte[1];
            statusdata[0] = 0x00;
            byte statuschecksum = CalculateChecksum(statusdata);
            Array.Resize(ref statusdata, statusdata.Length + 1);
            statusdata[statusdata.Length - 1] = statuschecksum;
            Random1(statusdata);
            Array.Resize(ref statusdata, statusdata.Length + 1);
            statusdata[statusdata.Length - 1] = 0x0A;
            foreach (byte b in statusdata)
            {
                //send the bytes to serial port
                 serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { b }, 0, 1);
            }
            //display stat us byte in richtextbox using invoke method
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Status Request Sent : " + BitConverter.ToString(statusdata) + "\n");
            });
            //run thread
            _ = Task.Run(() => { 
            while (true)
            {
                Task.Delay(100).Wait();
                if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    //read the single bytes from the serial port
                    byte buffer = (byte)serialPort1.ReadByte();
                    //if the byte is not a new line character, add it to the list
                    if (buffer != 0x0A)
                    {
                        //add the byte to the list
                        buffer_array[ind] = buffer;
                        //convert buffer to string and display it in the richtextbox
                        ind++;
                    }
                    else if (buffer == 0x0A)
                    {
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            richTextBox1.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(buffer_array) + " : " + ind + "\n");
                        });
                        byte[] new_array = new byte[ind];
                        //copy the buffer array to the new array
                        Array.Copy(buffer_array, new_array, ind);
                        Random1(new_array);
                        byte[] without_checksum_array = new byte[ind - 1];
                        Array.Copy(new_array, without_checksum_array, ind - 1);
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            richTextBox1.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(new_array) + " : " + ind + "\n");
                        });
                        byte checksum = CalculateChecksum(without_checksum_array);
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            richTextBox1.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(new_array) + " : " + ind + "\n");
                        });
                        if (checksum == new_array[ind - 1])
                        {
                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                richTextBox1.AppendText("Checksum is correct " + "\n");
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                richTextBox1.AppendText("Checksum is incorrect\n");
                            });
                        }
                        ind = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            });
        }
```

Comment: The c# random generate uses a seed to start the random generator.  The default constructor uses the Date/Time as the seed when the constructor has no parameters.  For code to work you need to use the same seed at both ends of the serial communications.  So use new Random(seed) and make the seed see the same at both ends of the serial port.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what randomization function you are using, but I can guarantee that it is not secure. At best it would protect against the most casual attacks. but if that is the goal I would suggest something simpler, like base64 encoding, or [ROT13 "encryption"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), that way it is obvious that no real security is expected.

If you want confidentiality, use an established and well tested encryption method, like AES. If you want to ensure message integrity use a [Message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code), or something similar. But if an attacker has physical access, as would be likely for serial communication, there is very little you can do without some form of Trusted platform chip.

If you want error *detection*, you can use a checksum as you are doing, but stronger error detection codes are available. There are also *[error correction codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code)* that can automatically fix bit-errors.

I would also be highly skeptical of any PRNG that used floating point numbers, since the result can depend on processor, optimizations, intermediate rounding etc. If you are committed to the idea, at least use an integer based PRNG.

Comment: Thank You very very much the problem is with PRNG and you are right I used the integer and my problem solve but i am using this method to check that is it reliable on low end devices which are not capable for complex process like encryption.